# How to redirect subdomain to a specific folder?

Tags: .htaccess, dns, subdomain

I create a subdomain called services and I want to redirect it to a folder, but I can't make it work.

I tried this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^services\.\.com.br$
RewriteRule ^/$ http://subdomain.mydomaintest/services/ [R,L]
```

The path to the folder is mydomain/web/services

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you :

```
# subdomain to subfolder
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^services\.com.br$
RewriteRule !service /services%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Does it take a time to work or it should work instantly? I'm asking because I tried to use your code but it's not working, the browser is returning "Hmmm… can't reach this page" :'(

Comment: @Lucky It should work instantly. What URL are you going to?

Comment: I'm getting a " Hmmm… can't reach this page" and DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"